# приложение для установки заблокировано play protect

Tags: android

При попытке установить подписанное приложение (app-release.apk) отображается предупреждение "Заблокировано Play Protect", и приложение не устанавливается. Однако неподписанное приложение (app-debug.apk) может быть установлено без проблем. Сообщение об ошибке: Play Protect не распознает разработчика этого приложения. Приложения от неизвестных разработчиков иногда могут быть небезопасны. Почему произошла эта ошибка? Каково решение?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кнопка INSTALL ANYWAY самое простое решение.

Comment: Ранее я не встречался с данной проблемой. Есть ли решение, которое поможет избавиться от этой проблемы с точки зрения разработки.

Comment: Сертификат подписи приложения содержит информацию о разработчике и машине, на которой он сгенерирован. Эта блокировка срабатывает на сертификат "неизвестного" разработчика. Соответственно, чтобы от неё избавиться, нужно стать "известным" - то есть опубликовать в гугло-маркете любое приложение, подписанное сертификатом, сгенерированным на том же ПК, с теми же данными о разработчике.

Comment: У меня другие приложения не опубликованы в google play, но они не выполняют данное действие.

Comment: Логика работы этого "защитника" известна только его разработчикам, потому как грошь цена такой защите, которую любой школьник сможет обойти. Если очень хочется - вытаскивайте с устройства приложение "Google Play" (или куда этот "Play Protect" зашит), декомпилируйте и изучайте как оно работает.

Comment: И тех кто устанавливает приложения не из маркета - никакие блокировки не пугают.